# Fonética: interrogações da Bíblia

Tags: tempo-verbal

Gostaria de entender melhor a forma que os livros da Bíblia discorrem suas palavras e interrogações.

Como entonar os tempos dos verbos e advérbios?

**Exemplo:**

> "Ele lhes disse: **por que temeis, homens de pequena fé?** Então,
>   levantou-se, repreendeu os ventos e o mar, e fez-se grande calmaria."
>   Mateus 8:26

Comment: Se eu entendi bem a tua pergunta, é sobre que intonação deve ser dada ao se ler a Bíblia para um público, principalmente no que toca aos verbos e advérbios.  Certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Centaurus

Comment: Acho difícil responder a uma pergunta sobre intonação, principalmente da Bíblia.  Vai muito da opinião pessoal de cada um.

Comment: Entendo @Centaurus, mas poderia ser essa frase: "por que vos não respondereis minha pergunta?"

Comment: Parece-me que esta pergunta tem pouco que ver com a língua portuguesa, exceto na medida em que a língua tem linhas melódicas típicas para diversos tipos de frases). Mas especificamente para a Bíblia, isso será mais uma questão de retórica.

Comment: Não percebo que é que isto tem que ver com a pergunta original, mas "por que vos não respondereis minha pergunta?" não faz muito sentido; a frase seria "por que vós não respondeis à minha pergunta", ou, em Portugal, "porque não respondeis vós à minha pergunta".

Comment: Entoação crescente, meio interrogação, meio exclamação, até "temeis." Na verdade a entoação de pergunta termina em "temeis"; "homens de pequena fé" é um vocativo (falta lá um vírgula). É como se fosse, "Por que temeis?! homens de pequena fé!"  Agora para ser mais claro, só mesmo com um ficheiro áudio. Talvez quem conheça notação musical possa ajudar...

Comment: @Jacinto, realmente estava faltando uma vírgula. A maneira que colocou, até "temeis" a pergunta, fica bem mais claro a interrogação.

Comment: @David Sem vírgula o significado ficava diferente também (*por que tendes medo de homens de pouca fé?* em vez de *homens de pouca fé, por que tendes medo?*). Encontrei [esta Bíblia narrada](https://www.wordproject.org/bibles/audio/04_portuguese/b40.htm). Com aquela entoação muito calma de padre. Eu gostaria de um pouco mais de energia.

Comment: @Jacinto encontrei essa [Naração](https://youtu.be/Cz-O7qMjSys?t=5m30s), um pouco diferente da frase que coloquei, mas entendi a forma de entoar da qual colocou.

Comment: David, acho essa pergunta demasiado... ampla. Podes tentar reduzir o âmbito da pergunta, por favor, @David ? Há demasiadas respostas: a entoação vai depender gramaticalmente da frase específica que é lida, da mensagem contida na frase, do leitor, do público alvo, da interpretação do leitor...